# Program dynamic select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a select that is full of data brought from my database, and what I want to do is that the user select an option to send it to the database and that this option no longer appears in the select, to avoid repeated fields in my database.

[image]

In the gif I'm just saying that the selection of "Queso" was already recorded in my database, I do not want to show more in my select

I understand that can be done with unique() in laravel migrations but I do not have very clear that method, any way that help me would serve for me.

This is the view

```
<div class="up">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm">
  <dd>Ahora selecciona los ingredientes del plato: </dd>
  <select name="ingrediente_id" id="ingrediente_id" class="form-control">
  <option selected>[ SELECCIONA UN INGREDIENTE ]</option>
   @foreach( $ingredientes as $ingrediente )
  <option value="{{ $ingrediente->id }}">{{ $ingrediente->nombre }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
</div>
```

I am using laravel 5.8, jQuery and Javascript

Comment: So your user can't have a double cheese?

Comment: Yes, the quantity of the ingredient is the input that is in the gif, it is another field in the base data.

Comment: mmmkay. I'll just start by saying what you're asking as very little to do with migrations. Migrations define the SQL tables and their rules. Please add the following informations: How are you getting the `$ingredientes` variable? What are the models attributes and relationships?